# vue ссылка на изображение

Tags: vue.js

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="@{{ imageLink }}"/>
</div>

var content = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        imageLink: 'https://любойдомен/someimage.jpg'
    }
});
```

Пробовал все варианты из документации:

```
<img v-bind:src="@{{ imageLink }}"/>
<img :src="@{{ imageLink }}"/>
```

Но каждый раз изображение не вставляется и появляется ошибка:

> invalid expression: Unexpected token { in
>
> ```
> {{ imageLink  }}
> ```
>
> Raw expression: :src="{{ imageLink  }}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

В данном случае необходимо указать для атрибута `src` директиву `v-bind`, или же сокращенно `:`, а саму переменную подставлять напрямую, как текст.

Документация:
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B

Пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    src: "http://1001goroskop.ru/img/gadanie/derevo_zh/_derevo.jpg"
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :src="src" />
</div>
```